# Is the true IP revealed when we simply view a web-page and the vpn connection drops?

Tags: web-browser, vpn

When someone surfs the internet, the ISP can see the webpages he/she is viewing only when a web page is loaded or refreshed? For example, if I am in this page typing my question and suddenly the vpn connection drops, is my true IP revealed?

Comment: If the VPN makes you appear to connect from a different IP address, and the VPN disconnects, then what do you logically think will happen the next time you connect to a website?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible under some circumstances. On this site for example, JavaScript code on the page periodically connects to the server to check for updates to content. This occurs without reloading the page. There are many other sites which have similar behavior.